Contradiction when estimating uncertainties with chi2 distribution
I have a contradiction when estimating parameter uncertainties using a likelihood function with independent Gaussian errors i.e.
log L ~ exp(-0.5 chi^2)
where chi^2 is the sum of the squared residuals.
The usual approach to estimate the uncertainties is to use the covariance matrix (e.g. when doing a least squares fit) or alternatively to find the variation of the parameters that vary the chi^2 by one (sometimes people use a somewhat larger number e.g. the number of model parameters to try to take into account possible correlations).
My problem is that there is an intrinsic uncertainty in the value of chi2. It has a mean equal to the number of degrees of freedom (N) and a variance of 2*N. So if I have 1,000 data points, even if my model is the true one I would expect to get a chi^2 of about 1,000 (assuming a have a small number of model parameters) with a standard deviation of 45. So if I have one model with a chi^2 of 950 and another model with chi^2 of 1,050 I cannot really favor one over the other.
But this seems to contradict the error estimation procedure of varying the chi2 by one or by a few to get the uncertainties. Obviously this comes from the exponential dependence of the likelihood function on the chi2, but how can these two facts be reconciled? Say I get a best fit chi2 of 950 for my 1,000 data points. I would estimate the parameters by finding the range of parameters that give chi2 less than 951 or some other small difference. But it seems like another model with a chi^2 of 1,050 would also be acceptable and this doesn't seem to be reflected in the parameter uncertainties.
How do I solve this contradiction?
Thanks.

I am unable to make sense of your question because (i) this log likelihood function doesn't even describe "Gaussian errors"; (ii) it appears to have nothing to do with a chi-squared distribution; and (iii) you seem to change your question in mid-stream where you mention some additional kind of "uncertainty" above and beyond what would be expressed by the likelihood.  Could you please tell us what your statistical setting is, describe your data, and lay our your statistical assumptions?

I think you're talking about the likelihood ratio test for nested models and the fact that it has a $\chi^2_p$ distribution if the two models differ by two parameters.
This isn't a contradiction because the loglikelihoods for the two model are not independent; they are strongly correlated because they are fitted to exactly the same data.
It turns out, in fact, that the loglikelihood for the larger model can be broken into two pieces $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ where $\ell_1$ is exactly the loglikelihood for the simple model and $\ell_2$ has asymptotically a $\chi^2_p$ distribution.  That is, the result works because the $\ell_1$ component of the loglikelihood for the more complex model is perfectly correlated (in large samples) with the whole loglikelihood for the simpler model
